# How to resolve `Missing artifact com.oracle:oracle-ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0` in maven

Tags: java, maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle-ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

While adding the above dependency I got error like `Missing artifact com.oracle:oracle-ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0` in maven.

I'm checking on the internet they are showing modify the user settings. And in my eclipse it looks like below:

```
Maven-->usersettings-->C:\Users\Jayanthraman\.m2\repository\settings.xml
```

Comment: Oracle jars are not present in maven central repositories. The simplest solution is to add an external dependency.

Comment: Oracle does not put its JDBC driver JARs in public repositories.  If you have a licensed copy of Oracle you should be able to find that JAR in your deployment.  You'll need to add it to your local .m2 or, better yet, an in-house central repo.

Comment: you could download the jar from oracle and add manually the dependency to your repository